# How to wrap ViewController content inside MDCTabBarView container?

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, material-components, material-components-ios

I'm trying to implement a `MDCBottomNavigationBar` which contains a `MDCTabBarView`, which in turn contains 2 other views (shown as tabbed).

In my main controller I create the 4 controllers for the menu items at the bottom and implement MDCTabBarViewDelegate. When the user taps on a bottom menu item, they are presented with the corresponding controller. Now I want one of the controllers to contain a tab bar at the top, as shown in the demo image below. I have created the same MDCTabBarViewDelegate with 2 controllers and added them to the view. They are shown and they are switching whenever I change the tabs, but there are issues with how it looks. So, `Tab 2` should contain the tab bar with `App` and `All`, and underneath the tab bar, the content of each tab should be shown.

Please check this image:
[Simulator Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hBvP.png)

The Green area should actually be the content of `Tab 2` -> `App`. The problem is the Green area is displayed on the entire screen, instead of being displayed under the tab bar. The second problem is that my view controllers are showing a faded bar above the bottom menu. I tried to hide that bar with `navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true` but nothing seems to work.

Can someone help me with the 2 issues above? I can't find a single resource / documentation about how to use this component on iOS. It would be great if you could even share some docs that I can read by myself, if not the answer.

Parent view controller:

```
class HomeController: UITabBarController {
    let firstC = FirstController()
    let secondC = SecondController()
    let thirdC = ThirdControllerController()
    let fourthC = FourthController()
    
    let bottomNavBar: MDCBottomNavigationBar = {
        let bottomNavBar = MDCBottomNavigationBar()
        
        bottomNavBar.titleVisibility = .always
        bottomNavBar.alignment = .justifiedAdjacentTitles
        
        return bottomNavBar
    }()
    
    let firstItem: MDCTabBarItem = {
        let firstItem = MDCTabBarItem()
        
        firstItem.title = "Tab 1"
        firstItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "house.fill")
        firstItem.tag = 0
        
        return firstItem
    }()
    
    let secondItem: MDCTabBarItem = {
        let secondItem = MDCTabBarItem()
        
        secondItem.title = "Tab 2"
        secondItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "house.fill")
        secondItem.tag = 1
        
        return secondItem
    }()
    
    let thirdItem: MDCTabBarItem = {
        let thirdItem = MDCTabBarItem()
        
        thirdItem.title = "Tab 3"
        thirdItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "house.fill")
        thirdItem.tag = 2
        
        return thirdItem
    }()
    
    let fourthItem: MDCTabBarItem = {
        let fourthItem = MDCTabBarItem()
        
        fourthItem.title = "Tab 4"
        fourthItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "house.fill")
        fourthItem.tag = 3
        
        return fourthItem
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        bottomNavBar.delegate = self
        
        bottomNavBar.items = [firstItem, secondItem, thirdItem, fourthItem]
        self.viewControllers = [
                firstC,
                secondC,
                thirdC,
                fourthC
            ]
        
        view.addSubview(bottomNavBar)
    }
}

// SecondC - inner controller

class SecondController: UITabBarController {
    let firstC = TabFirstC()
    let secondC = TabSecondC()

    let firstTab: MDCTabBarItem = {
        let tab = MDCTabBarItem(title: "App", image: nil, tag: 0)
        
        return tab
    }()
    
    let secondTab: MDCTabBarItem = {
        let tab = MDCTabBarItem(title: "All", image: nil, tag: 1)
        return tab
    }()
    
    let tabs: MDCTabBarView = {
        let tabs = MDCTabBarView()
        tabs.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tabs
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(tabs)
        
        viewControllers = [firstC, secondC]
        tabs.tabBarDelegate = self
        tabs.items = [firstTab, secondTab]
        tabs.selectedItem = firstTab
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tabs.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            tabs.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logoImageView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            tabs.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        ])

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide some of the code you're using to create what you have so far. It is much easier to provide feedback and help when other's can see the code you're working with so far.

Comment: @DanO'Leary I added the controller code in the original question.